# Galleria lightbox with thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, gallery, galleria

I have a website on Joomla 3.1. And have a plugin for the articles to show images (Avatar Slide Galleria plugin (http://joomavatar.com/demos/j16/index.php/slide-show-imagecontent/avatar-slide-galleria/classic-theme)).

Everything is all right and the gallery matches my needs. The only thing I would like to add is when the gallery opens in lightbox, the thumbnails also appear there.

I have been searching for solutions quite a lot and the answers I meet are not what I want. Everyone suggests that I should use some additional plugin of jquery. But I would like to overcome the matter without any additional large amount of coding. If possible to make changes in the galleria-1.2.9.js.

Has anyone met this kind of problem and is there a simple solution for me?

Thanks!

Comment: :- have you found any solution for that ..

Comment: no, unfortunately I did not